# Follow Hyperlinks, Text.ToDisplay is dynamic

Tags: vb.net

I have some hyperlinks on my spreadsheet and use the Select Case Target.TextToDisplay to follow the hyperlinks. They all work fine except for one hyperlink in cell E25. The hyperlink is created, but because the value of the cell is dynamic (changes with the selection of a combobox), I cannot set a specific text to find and follow the hyperlink. I created a variable and tried to use that value to follow the hyperlink, but it would not. The hyperlink is supposed to open a pdf report.

Here is what I wrote, again, the hyperlink is created, but when clicked it does not open the report. The issue is on the last Case. The attached screenshot shows the hyperlinked cell. As the combobox values change so does the value in E25. The link is supposed to go to a pdf report with the same name plus .pdf [image]

```
Private Sub dsbPositionBoard_FollowHyperlink(Target As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Hyperlink) Handles Me.FollowHyperlink

'This procedure runs when any of the hyperlinked cells in the position dashboard are clicked
'The hyperlinks open the frmDefinition on the assigned defintion. The procedure calls
'the function. 

'The hyperlinked cells are assigned under the ThisWorkbook/Open event.

Dim definitionForm As New frmDefinitions

xlWB = CType(Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
xlWSPOS = CType(xlWB.Sheets("positionBoard"), Excel.Worksheet)

Dim xlRng As Excel.Range = DirectCast(xlWSPOS.Range("E25"), Excel.Range)
Dim jobCodeReport As String = DirectCast(xlRng.Value.ToString, String)
Dim xlWBPath As String

xlWBPath = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Select Case Target.TextToDisplay

    Case "Exempt"
        definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
        sheetView.exemptDefinition()

    Case "Employee Pay Distribution for Ranges", "Low Third", "Upper Third"
        definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
        sheetView.lowerThirdDefinition()

    Case "Market Percentiles"
        definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
        sheetView.marketPercentileDefinition()

    Case "Min", "Mid", "Max", "Salary Range to Mkt"
        definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
        sheetView.payGradeWidthDefintion()

    Case "Total Cash Compensation Data"
        definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
        sheetView.totalCashCompDefition()

    Case "Compa-Ratio"
        definitionForm.tmr_out.Enabled = True
        sheetView.compaRatioDefinition()

    Case "Click here to build ranges"
        customRanges()

    Case "T-test Results", "Median Test Results"
        Globals.refCohortAnalysis.Select()

    Case jobCodeReport
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(xlWBPath & "\" & jobCodeReport & ".pdf")


End Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a case statement for each ComboBox Option, then depending on what case (string) is selected open your .pdf that way.